# Can I convert JSON data to POJO by using default message converter?

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring

I know `MappingMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is default, but I got

> JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'Stock': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Stock': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

I think that maybe the reason is `MappingMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` can not convert JSON data to custom POJO and we have to add `new HttpMessageConverter` by `@Overide` method `extendMessageConverters()`:

```
/**
 * A hook for extending or modifying the list of converters after it has been
 * configured. This may be useful for example to allow default converters to
 * be registered and then insert a custom converter through this method.
 * @param converters the list of configured converters to extend.
 * @since 4.1.3
 */
default void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) 

{
}
```

Or is it not necessary？

I have tried different JSON style: `{"id":"1"}`,`{"Stock":{"id":"1"}}`. But neither worked.

```
public class myWebApplication extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
  }  

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
  }
}

WebConfig(DispatcherServlet):

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"WebBeans"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
  @Override
  public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/jsp/",".jsp");
  }

  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
   configurer.enable();
  }
}
```

My POJO:

```
public class Stock 
{
  private String id;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/getid2?",
      data: {
        "Stock": {
          "id": "" + $("#id").val()
        }
      },
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      success: function() {
        console.log("successful upload!")
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("err!")
      }
    });
  })
});
```

I find this in the [SpringMVC Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody):

```
@PostMapping("/accounts")
public void handle(@Valid @RequestBody Account account, BindingResult result) 
{
  // ...
}
```

It seems like `@RequestBody` could convert JSON data to POJO, but it does not work for me. I get Error 400 on Chrome

Request Payload:

```
Stock%5Bid%5D=4
```

And

> JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'Stock': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Stock': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')`

What is the reason?

Comment: Could you add the `Account` class ?

Comment: Could you please attache json you receiving from frontend? The error tels you that you are trying to set Stock value to Bollean variable

Comment: @Arnaud That comes from Spring Doc and `Account` is not listed.

Comment: Hi @alexey28 ,`Stock%5Bid%5D=4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending incorrect json to backend:

```
Stock%5Bid%5D=4
```

Correct request body (to be parsed by json converter) should be:

```
{
  "id": "4"
}
```

I think the fix might be:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: '{"id": "4"}', // Also will work JSON.stringify({id: "4"})
    ...
});
```